# Remove comma from citation after connector (&)

Tags: citing, apacite

I am publishing a paper for a convention that asked me to remove the citation commas before & in my quotes. I'm using this [conference template](https://sol.sbc.org.br/journals/index.php/rbie/libraryFiles/downloadPublic/3) and have not customizes anything in the project for citation. It looks like the template is using the `apacite` citation management package along with `myapacite.bst` to format citation call-outs and the bibliographic entries themselves.

Whenever I cite like this:

```
@article{geurts2006extremely,
  title={Extremely randomized trees},
  author={Geurts Pierre and Ernst Damien and Wehenkel Louis},
  journal={Machine learning},
  volume={63},
  number={1},
  pages={3--42},
  year={2006},
  publisher={Springer},
  doi={10.1007/s10994-006-6226-1}
}

\cite{geurts2006extremely}
```

I get an output such as

```
(Pierre, Damien, & Louis, 2006)
```

I am new to latex and am stuck on trying to remove the comma before & and make it look like this:

```
(Pierre, Damien & Louis, 2006)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you show the contents of the `.bib` file for this specific entry (`geurts2006extremely`)? It is rather strange that a conference provides you with a template and then not accept the output of that template - but maybe the bibliography entry is formatted incorrectly which causes the extra comma.

Comment: hi @Marijn, just added the bib entry for the reference. Yeah, If I cannot figure out a solution i will contact them asking for help

Comment: The first names and last names are swapped (it should be either `author = {Pierre Geurts and Damien Ernst and Louis Wehenkel}` or `author = {Geurts, Pierre and Ernst, Damien and Wehenkel, Louis}`) but that is unrelated to the comma issue I think.

Comment: I copied the quote from google scholar's bibtex snippet. Changing the order as suggested did not change the citation, but did change the values of the citing to be like this

 (Geurts, Ernst, & Wehenkel, 2006)

Comment: I tried the template from your link myself (unchanged) and there the comma is also present, so asking the conference organizers seems the right thing to do. The new output (Geurts, Ernst, & Wehenkel) is correct though (and the previous one incorrect), as these are the family names of the authors. Google Scholar BibTeX items are automatically generated and they are not always fully correct, it is always good to check manually if the result is as expected.

Comment: Repeat after me: "Just because some bibliographic entry may be found in Google Scholar provides no guarantee whatsoever that the bibliographic information is correct."

Comment: thanks for the advice @Mico

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The document class you employ loads the `apacite` package. I suggest you run

```
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\BCBT}{} \renewcommand{\BCBL}{}}
```

in the preamble to achieve your formatting objective. See p. 34 of the user guide of the [apacite](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/apacite) package for further explanations.

And, you should -- actually, *must* -- change the `author` line to

```
  author={Geurts, Pierre and Ernst, Damien and Wehenkel, Louis},
```

Comment: thank you so much, it worked